# How to use sysargv module in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, rdkit

I've been trying to filter database of molecules based on their strucutre similaritsy to reference molecules, but the script is not working because od warning 'An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.' I'm using jupyter notebook in vs code.

The line in questions is:
if len(sys.argv)!=5 :
sys.exit("usage : python tetheredMinimization.py reference.sdf output1.sdf outputtethered.sdf outputnontethered.sdf")

> ```
> import sys 
> from rdkit import Chem 
> from rdkit.Chem import AllChem 
> from rdkit.Chem import rdFMCS 
> from rdkit.Chem.rdMolAlign import AlignMol
> ```
>
> if len(sys.argv)!=5 :
> sys.exit("usage : python tetheredMinimization.py reference.sdf output1.sdf outputtethered.sdf
> outputnontethered.sdf")
>
> ratioThreshold=0.20
>
> reference = Chem.MolFromMolFile(sys.argv[1], removeHs=True)
> ligands = Chem.SDMolSupplier(sys.argv[2],removeHs=True)
>
> w=Chem.SDWriter(sys.argv[3])
> wnt=Chem.SDWriter(sys.argv[4])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jupyter, you probably do not want to be using `sys.argv`, this is usually used to retrieve [command-line arguments](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/). Used in Jupyter you most likely will get the arguments used for launching IPython which is also likely not to satisfy `len(sys.argv) == 5`. Instead of using this just define your arguments within the code and replace all places you have used `sys.argv` with the correct variable.